# git bisect manual vs git bisect run

Tags: git, binary-search-tree, git-bisect

I'm learning about `git bisect`

Let's guess the following linear git history:

```
* A commit-1     # HEAD
* B commit-2
* C commit-3
* D commit-4     # First bad commit
* E commit-5
* F commit-6
* G commit-7
* H commit-8     # Is good
```

---

Then, I start the bisection:

```
git bisect start
git bisect bad HEAD      # A commit-1
git bisect good H        # H commit-8
```

I have a script that run some tests, if I run the tests manually and mark every commit as *bad* and *good*, it follows these steps:

```
E commit-5     # OK
C commit-3     # FAIL
D commit-4     # FAIL
```

So, it finishes saying the `D commit-4` is the first bad commit, **which is correct**.

---

But, if I go by using `git bisect run ../outside/test.sh` it does the following:

```
E commit-5     # OK
C commit-3     # FAIL
B commit-2     # FAIL
A commit-1     # FAIL
```

Saying that `A commit-1` is the first bad commit, **which is wrong**.

So, if I understand the binary search here, once `C commit-3` is bad, the first bad commit should be itself or be below.

What I'm missing here?
Why they turns out to have different behaviour?
Looks like `git bisect run` is running a different algorithm.

My git version is: `2.19.0`

Thanks

Comment: did you `git bisect reset` before starting with the second bisect session (i.e. the automated run)?

Comment: Yes, I did it.
Actually, I repeated both process twice, but got the same result

Comment: Is (are?) your test-repository-and-test-script generally available, e.g., on GitHub or similar?

Comment: It's a private repo, but I'm going to prepare a public example and check how it goes

Comment: Hmm, looks a bit like your `test.sh` returns the wrong exit status. If the result is `OK`, it should return `0`.

Comment: Yes I know, it was just to show the OK word, but the script is returning 0 for success and 1 for error.

Comment: I suspect that `git bisect run` runs `./test.sh` in a slightly different environment. My advice is to log the current directory and content of environment (`pwd` and `set`) when `./test.sh` is being run directly and from `git bisect run`.

Comment: @phd the script tests is outside of the repository, does it affect the result?

Comment: Hard to say without a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Just found the issue:

My script was:

```
#!/bin/bash

npm test
echo "STATUS: $?"

exit $?
```

So when `npm start` was returning `1`, the `echo` statement, change the latest exit code to `0` which is the one I was using in `exit`.

Thanks for pointing out the `script`.